# The Scope of Common Lisp Declaim (eg, for Optimization)

Tags: common-lisp, compiler-optimization

The Common Lisp Hyperspec entry for `declaim` says: "it is unspecified whether or not the compile-time side-effects of a declaim persist after the file has been compiled."  Does this mean that compiler optimization settings (for portability) should be included in each project file, as opposed to only in the init file (intended globally)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730012/common-lisp-asdf-tests-compile-system-with-different-optimization-levels